# Generate 4 columns of data such that each row sum to 100

Tags: python

How do I write a python program that can randomly generate 4 columns of data such that the sum of the numbers of each row is 100?

Comment: Can we repeat numbers? Are negatives allowed?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: sounds like homework

Comment: Yes can repeat numbers. Numbers should be positive real number.s

Comment: This is a puzzle, not a programming assignment. If you know how to use `random.randint()` or `random.randrange()` then all you have to do is figure out how to create 4 numbers that add up to 100. Hint: What is the 4th number if you already generated 3?

Comment: I understand logic how to do it but I am not familiar with Python. So I can use random.randrange() and how can I organize it so it displays as 4 columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.random.rand(10,4)
>>> A /= A.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
>>> A *= 100
>>> A

array([[ 52.65020485,   8.39068184,   4.89730114,  34.06181217],
       [ 58.32667159,   8.99338257,  13.7326809 ,  18.94726494],
       [  8.23847677,  36.27990343,  14.73440883,  40.74721097],
       [ 37.10408209,   5.31467062,  39.47977538,  18.10147191],
       [ 21.5697797 ,  14.80630725,  12.69891923,  50.92499382],
       [ 15.46006657,  24.62499701,  37.37736874,  22.53756768],
       [  6.66777748,  25.62326117,  11.80042839,  55.90853296],
       [ 38.81602256,  26.74457165,   3.4365655 ,  31.00284028],
       [  5.67431732,   7.57571558,  44.01330459,  42.73666251],
       [ 33.09837171,  26.66421892,  10.90188895,  29.33552043]])
```

This generates positive real numbers as you asked.  They will be random in the uniform distribution.  If you want a different distribution, you can find several other choices in `np.random`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def Column(n):
    integers = []
    for i in range(n):
        A = random.randrange(0,100)
        B = random.randrange(0,100-A)
        C = random.randrange(0,100-(A+B))
        D = (100 - (A+B+C))
        integers.append((A,B,C,D))
    return integers

Returns = Column(4)
for i in Returns:
    print(i)
    print(i[0]+i[1]+i[2]+i[3])
```

Sorry if it's messy, got to go.

Comment: 1) I think this will bunch up the numbers, so it is not actually random but skewed.  2) It can also fail with `ValueError` pretty easily, consider the case where A or B was 0.  3) You don't prevent D from becoming negative with this method.

Comment: I know negative numbers can occur, but I assumed as long as the sum was 100 it would be ok. But I now see he wanted no negatives. I'll edit it when I get home . .

Comment: Fixed Negative number issue. No negatives now. However, like @wim said, the numbers are going to be influenced by the method I am using to make sure it adds correctly.