# Generate combinations such that the total is always 100 and uses a defined jump value

Tags: python, numpy, range, combinations

I am looking to generate a list of combinations such that the total is always 100. The combinations have to be generated based on a jump value (similar to how we use it in range or loop).
The number of elements in each combination is based on the length of the parent_list. If the parent list of 10 elements, we need each list in the output to be of 10 elements.

```
parent_list=['a','b','c', 'd']
jump=15
```

sample of expected output is

```
[[15,25,25,35],[30,50,10,10],[20,15,20,45]]
```

I used the solution given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610059/generate-4-columns-of-data-such-that-each-row-sum-to-100), but it doesn't give the option to add the Jump parameter. Fractions are allowed too.

Comment: Can you explain how "30, 50, 10, 10" is generated "based on a jump value" of 15?

Comment: The first element has been incremented by 15 so the total is 30. The rest of the 70 divided into the remaining 3 elements.

Comment: Sorry, but it's very unclear what you mean. Where does the question come from? Can you give a link or summarize the text of the original question? Or at least put in the question the rules for generating the first and subsequent "combinations".

Comment: The question is about distribution. Lets say, I have 100 $ and I want to distribute it among a group of people. What the ways in which it can be divided. The answer could be infinite combinations. So to limit it, we add the Jump variable. We can start iteration by giving one person 15 and find the other division options. Then increase the first person holding by 15 more than find other division options. After the first person reaches the max, use the jump variable for the second person and so on...Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Find 4 numbers that add up to 100 such that at least one of them is a multiple of 15. Is that an accurate way of stating your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program finds all combinations of `n` positive integers whose sum is `total` such that at least one of them is a multiple of `jump`. It works in a recursive way, setting `jump` to 1 if the current sequence already contains an element that's a multiple of the original `jump`.

```
def find_sum(n, total, jump, seq=()):
    if n == 0:
        if total == 0 and jump == 1: yield seq
        return
    for i in range(1, total+1):
        yield from find_sum(n - 1, total - i, jump if i % jump else 1, seq + (i,))

for seq in find_sum(4, 100, 15):
    print(seq)
```

There's still a lot of solutions.

Comment: Looks like it works. I am still testing it. After posting the question, I was thinking about the question and it is similar to the gradient descent in the neural networks.The jump is basically the variable that controls the combinations.

Comment: right now, it yields integers. is there a way to include fractions also in the output?

Comment: I've given you a lot of help already, figuring out how to express the problem and then solving it, so perhaps you should ask a new question if you want an extended version involving fractions. You're obviously very imaginative with your ideas but you need to be able to focus your question-asking so that it's possible for other people to be able to help you.

Comment: :) Your solution has already helped me at lot.